# How to complete "letters" function? (linked list)

Tags: c, count, linked-list, char, store

I'm beginner at linked list and I hope someone help me.

The homework wants: input string (from user), store it in linked list and count the letters that appeared. For example: input:hello output:hello h:1 e:1 l:2 o:1.

I have the code below at this time and I want a little help with "letters" function. Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct charact {
    char ch;
    int occurs;
    struct charact *next;
};

typedef struct charact Char;
typedef Char *ListofChar;
typedef Char *CharNode_ptr;
void letters(char name[50], ListofChar *chars_ptr);
void report(ListofChar chars);
Char *createnode(char ch);

int main() {
    char name[50];
    ListofChar chars = NULL;
    scanf("%s", name);
    letters(name, &chars);
    report(chars);
    return 0;
}

Char *createnode(char ch) {
    CharNode_ptr newnode_ptr ;
    newnode_ptr = malloc(sizeof (Char));
    newnode_ptr -> ch = ch;
    newnode_ptr -> occurs = 0;
    newnode_ptr -> next = NULL;
    return newnode_ptr;
}
/*code*/
void letters(char name[50], ListofChar *lst_ptr) {

    int i;
    Char *temp=NULL;
    Char *p=NULL;
    for(i=0;name[i]!='\0';i++){
        createnode(name[i]);
    }

    return;
}

void report(ListofChar chars) {
    while(chars!=NULL){
        printf("%c",chars->ch);
        chars=chars->next;
}
return;
}
```

Comment: Important hint: dont hide pointers behind typedefs like here: `typedef Char * ListofChar;`. It only adds confusion. E.g. here: `CharNode_ptr newnode_ptr; newnode_ptr = malloc(sizeof(Char));` is actually the same thing as `char* newnode_ptr; newnode_ptr = malloc(sizeof(Char));`. You see the problem now?

Comment: Sorry, forget the part from "E.g." in my first comment. I got confused by your awkward typedef: `typedef struct charact Char;`. Read again the first par of that comment.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yes but I think that this part its ok and my problem is how to use Char *createnode(char ch) in letters function, so I can print the user's input. Thank you!

Comment: `createnode` creates a new node and returns the pointer to the newly created node. But when you call `createnode(name[i]);` you don't do anything with the returned node. Each new node must be linked to the previous node. Google "linked list C" for more information.

Comment: @Jabberwocky So I have to write in "letters" something like that is in createnode. Right?

Answer (score 1):

For an unput of "Hel" this is roughly the list you want to create:

```
+------+
|  H   |
+------+
| next |-+
+------+ |
   ------|
   |
   V
+------+
|  E   |
+------+
| next |-+
+------+ |
   ------|
   |
   V
+------+
|  L   |
+------+
| NULL |
+------+
```

and this is what your code creates:

```
+------+
|  H   |
+------+
| NULL |
+------+

+------+
|  E   |
+------+
| NULL |
+------+

+------+
|  L   |
+------+
| NULL |
+------+
```

You need to link the elements of your list together. With this drawing and searching on google you should be able to write your program.

Comment: Can you please explain me what is `*ListofChar` at `typedef Char *ListofChar;`? I know that Char is a new "node" but I can not understand what is the pointer in front of it.

Comment: Sorry, I mean Char is a new struct for linked list, so I can not understand the use of `*ListofChar`.